# Assume always-trust is yes/true in GPG cmd

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd, system.diagnostics, gnupg

Im using GPG to encrypt a file in ASP.NET, C#. My code executes the command using ProcessStartInfo, and gpg.exe executes, but I have an issue. GPG asks me to authorize always-trust with "y" as the option. I tried using "YES" as well (As suggested in GPG help, to assume "yes" for all questions), but that didn't work either.

The string that runs GPG is:

```
"gpg --armor --output fileOutput.gpg --recipient secure@site.com --encrypt fileInput.xml --always-trust --yes"
```

The question that's prompted is:

> It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named in the
>   user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing, you may answer the
>   next question with yes
>
> Use this key anyway?

How can I ignore the question altogether, or force the answer to be true ("YES") without being prompted to confirm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

add `--always-trust` as a command line argument to gpg to take the prompt away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendKeys.SendWait`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need only to specify the trust model "always" by using the "--trust-model" option.

For Example:

```
gpg --trust-model always --armor --output fileOutput.gpg --recipient secure@site.com --encrypt fileInput.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Pipe a "y" to your command:

```
echo "y" | <your command>
```

Comment: sorry but don't work for me.. i reading for cmd_exec.StandardInput.WriteLine